# Django mongoengine - filter string that does not contains values from list

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I'm trying to filter objects from mongodb using mongoengine in django.

Assuming I have the following class:

```py
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
```

I wanna filter all Person objects whose name does not contain "Jhon" or "Doe".

I can achieve this with that code:

```py
Person.objects.filter(
    name__not__contains="Jhon"
).filter(
    name__not__contains="Doe"
)
```

But I wanna do that with only one 'filter' calling.

I've already tryed that:

```py
Person.objects.filter(name__not__contains=["Jhon", "Doe"])
```

But I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py", line 144, in count
    return super().count(with_limit_and_skip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 399, in count
    count = self._cursor.count(with_limit_and_skip=with_limit_and_skip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1666, in _cursor
    self._cursor_obj = self._collection.find(self._query, **self._cursor_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1715, in _query
    self._mongo_query = self._query_obj.to_query(self._document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py", line 90, in to_query
    query = query.accept(QueryCompilerVisitor(document))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py", line 185, in accept
    return visitor.visit_query(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py", line 79, in visit_query
    return transform.query(self.document, **query.query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/transform.py", line 120, in query
    value = field.prepare_query_value(op, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 152, in prepare_query_value
    value = re.escape(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 276, in escape
    return bytes(s)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Is that possible to achieve what I'm trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the entire strings, you can achieve this with `__nin` [query operators](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators)

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()

john = Person(name="John").save()
bob = Person(name="Bob").save()
fu = Person(name="Fu").save()

persons = list(Person.objects(name__nin=["John", "Bob"]))
assert len(persons) == 1
assert persons[0] == fu
```

If you want to use "not contains", you can combine the conditions with the [Q operator](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries) e.g

```
Person.objects(Q(name__not__contains="John") | Q(name__not__contains="F"))
```

Comment: But how to apply that with the 'contains' operatos, i.e., if there is a 'Person' with name "Johnny" (contains "John"). In that case, `assert len(persons) == 1` gives `AssertionError`.

Comment: `len(list(Person.objects(Q(name__not__contains="John") | Q(name__not__contains="F"))))` returns `3`. Did you mean `Q (name__not__contains = "Bob")` and did you want to use the AND ("&") operator? `len(list(Person.objects(Q(name__not__contains="John") & Q(name__not__contains="Bob"))))` returns `1`. @bagerard

Comment: indeed, you can turn it the way you want, you get the idea. Didn't it answer your question?

Comment: I actually need to pass a dynamic array. So, this will not solve my problem.